# Compact sets closed in Hausdorff spaces without choice?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, axiom-of-choice

An elementary proof that compact sets are closed in Hausdorff spaces involves making arbitrary choices based on the Hausdorff property. Is there a way to avoid invoking choice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is.

Let $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ be a Hausdorff space, and let $K$ be a compact subset of $X$. Suppose that $K$ is not closed. Then we can pick $p\in(\operatorname{cl}K)\setminus K$. (Note that this does not require $\mathsf{AC}$: it’s a single choice.) Let

$$\mathscr{U}=\{U\in\tau:p\notin\operatorname{cl}U\}\;.$$

- $K\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr{U}$.

If not, pick $x\in K\setminus\bigcup\mathscr{U}$. $X$ is Hausdorff, so there are disjoint $U,V\in\tau$ such that $x\in U$ and $p\in V$. But then $U\in\mathscr{U}$, contradicting the choice of $x$. Note that I picked only three things here, $x$, $U$, and $V$; this does not require $\mathsf{AC}$.

$K$ is compact, so there is a finite $\{U_1,\ldots,U_n\}\subseteq\mathscr{U}$ such that $K\subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^nU_k$. Then

$$p\notin\bigcup_{k=1}^n\operatorname{cl}U_k=\operatorname{cl}\bigcup_{k=1}^nU_k\supseteq\operatorname{cl}K\;,$$

contradicting the choice of $p$. Therefore $K$ is closed.

Comment: Thanks. These sorts of problems have been bugging me recently where choice isn't explicitly mentioned in the proof but is left for the reader to determine if it really requires choice or not. This is really frequent when dealing with compact things to produce open covers and such. Is it usually the case, in elementary textbooks in topology, when choice isn't mentioned that the proof doesn't require it? Or are there any general strategies to help determine whether or not something requires choice?

Comment: @user200582: Topologists generally take choice pretty much for granted; after all, $\mathsf{AC}$ is equivalent to the Tikhonov product theorem, which is one of the most important theorems in topology. With practice and attention it’s not too hard to recognizing when one actually *is* using choice; knowing whether it was necessary is another matter altogether. Horst Herrlich, *Axiom of Choice*, Springer Lecture Notes in Mathematics $1875$, has a lot of information on the topic.

Comment: @user200582: The word "choice" is used ambiguously in mathematics. One usage involves the axiom of choice. The other involves simply invoking a basic principle of logic called "instantiating an existential quantifier", namely, if the statement $\exists x P(x)$ is true, then you are allowed to "choose" an $x$ such that $P(x)$ is true (I think of this as the power of Adam: you may name things). Brian's proof involves three usages of instantiating an existential quantifier.